# Find the value of the prime $p$ knowing that $p>5$ and $p│(3^{p+1} +5^{p-1} + 1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I am trying to find the value of $p$, a prime number of which we only know that $p>5$ and:

$p│(3^{p+1}  +5^{p-1}  + 1)$

This is part of a collection of exercises regarding divisibility, Fermat's little theorem and congruences (among others).

Seeing that the second term has $5^{p-1}$, I imagine Fermat's little theorem could be used on that, but I don't know how to advance from there.

Any help/hints are welcome!

(currently stuck trying to take the value from the main expression knowing that  $3^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$ and $3^{p-1}*3^2\equiv 3^2\bmod p$, so $3^{p+1}\equiv 3^2\bmod p$, also $5^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$)

Comment: Hint: $3^{p+1}=3^{p-1}\cdot 3^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $p│3^{p+1}+5^{p-1}+1$, that is the same as saying that $3^{p+1}+5^{p-1}+1\equiv 0\bmod p$. But you know the values of $3^{p+1}\bmod p$ and $5^{p-1}\bmod p$.

Comment: thanks, so $3^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$ and $3^{p-1}*3^2\equiv 3^2\bmod p$, so $3^{p+1}\equiv 3^2\bmod p$, also $5^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$, but I am not sure how to go from there in the "main" congruence

Comment: @Lightsong: Now it's easy! I can't see your problem, I'm afraid.

Comment: I literally don't know what to do after that

Comment: $3^{p+1}+5^{p-1}+1\equiv 0\bmod p$

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how to manipulate the congruence so that I can "substract" terms  (I assume it has to be done like that), in order to get the value of $p$

Comment: @Lightsong: You mean you can get as far as $11\equiv 0\bmod p$, but then you get stuck? That is hard to believe.

Comment: No, I mean I cannot get  to $11 \equiv 0\bmod p$ by manipulating the main congruence

Comment: @metamorphy: FLT usually means Fermat's _Last_ Theorem, not Fermat's Little Theorem.